# Augmented Matrix with a constant in 'A'

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have an augmented matrix defined:

$$\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
      1&   0&   2&  1\\
      0&   1&  -1&  2\\
      1&  -2& k+4&  5
    \end{array}\right]$$

where 'k' is an unspecified, but fixed, number.

> #### Question
>
> What restriction on the value of 'k' ensures that the system has
>   solution(s)?

I have never seen a constant in an augmented matrix before and do not really get what it is asking for in regards to the question. Am I missing something completely simple here?

Any push in the right direction will be helpful

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Substract the first row from the thrid one and get the equivalent system

$$\begin{pmatrix}1&0&2&1\\0&1&\!\!-1&2\\0&\!\!-2&k+2&4\end{pmatrix}$$

and now add twice the second row to the last one:

$$\begin{pmatrix}1&0&2&1\\0&1&\!\!-1&2\\0&0&k&8\end{pmatrix}$$

It follows at once that the system has solution iff $\,k\neq 0\,$ (why?)

Comment: Right! so the idea is to get k by itself?

Comment: @MichaelCoxon, I honestly don't understand what you mean by that. Imo, the idea is to reduce (by rows, in this case) the given matrix by means of elementary operations and at the end to obtain the condition(s) that assure the system is congruent (or has at least one solution)

Comment: Yeah, I just wrote it out and it makes sense now. It's like you just ignore the 'k' and make the associated value 0 so that only k remains. Thanks for your help!